# Using Sharepoint CSOM, how to check for null when retrieving content type by Id

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I attempt to locate a content type by id first at the current web level, if not found then i check from the root web. However at the current web if not found I don't know of the right way to check if the content type was found. One way that works is the following but it throws an exception and I would like to avoid that approach.

How does one check if returned content type is found?

```
            ContentType cType =
            clientContext.Web.ContentTypes.GetById(contentType.Id);
            clientContext.Load(cType);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            try
            {
                if (cType.Id == null)
                {
                    cType = clientContext.Web.ContentTypes.GetById(contentType.Id);

                }
            }catch(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerObjectNullReferenceException nullException)
            {
                cType = clientContext.Site.RootWeb.ContentTypes.GetById(contentType.Id);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Every Content Type have name and Id, this is necessary for Content Type, check if content type existed in current web like this:

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClientContext clientContext=new ClientContext("http://sp/");
            ContentType cType = null;
            try
            {
                    cType = clientContext.Web.ContentTypes.GetById("0x0101004B81B8917C303D47BEA5E576CB73DF88");
                    clientContext.Load(cType);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cType.Name))
                    {
                        cType = clientContext.Web.ContentTypes.GetById("0x0120D520A808");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Content Type not existed in current web.");
                    }
            }
            catch (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerObjectNullReferenceException nullException)
            {

            }
        }
```

[image]

cType is not null when it is invaild at all:
[image]

Comment: There is no way to test that i have a valid Content type without it throwing an exception?

Comment: @monkeyjumps, when getting a invalid Content Type, checking the Content Type name, it will throw the null exception, I will update the capture in my reply.

Comment: right! that is what i discovered but i was hoping there was a better approach.

Comment: @monkeyjumps, this should be the best approach to check Id or name as when a Content Type is invalid, the Content Type Object itself won't be null.